# array grouping conversion key start_section to end_section

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Let's say I have below array :

```
[{id: 1, name: "header"},{id: 2, name: "start_section"},
 {id: 3, name: "input"}, {id: 5, name: "image"},
 {id: 6, name: "end_section"}, {id: 7, name: "header"},
 {id: 8, name: "start_section"}, {id: 9, name: "input"},
 {id: 10, name: "date"}, {id: 11, name: "end_section"},
]
```

I want this :

```
[{
  id: 1,
  name: "header"
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: "section",
  child: [{
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "input"
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      name: "image"
    },
  }],
}, {
  id: 7,
  name: "header"
}, {
  id: 8,
  name: "section",
  child: [{
    {
      id: 9,
      name: "input"
    },
    {
      id: 10,
      name: "date"
    },
  }]
}]
```

if I find start_section and end_section then it will form a new object , How do I change the array by grouping by the key specified in the example above in javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get it right, you want something like this? It's simple approach with `for` loop and some flags:

```js
const arr = [{id: 1, name: "header"},{id: 2, name: "start_section"},
 {id: 3, name: "input"}, {id: 5, name: "image"},
 {id: 6, name: "end_section"}, {id: 7, name: "header"},
 {id: 8, name: "start_section"}, {id: 9, name: "input"},
 {id: 10, name: "date"}, {id: 11, name: "end_section"},
];

// Set final array
let finalArray = [];

// Set sub object for groups (Childs)
let subObj = {};

// Flag for sub section stuff
let inSubSection = false;

// Loop array
for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if(arr[i].name === "end_section") {
    // If we have end_section
    // Set flag off
    inSubSection = false;
    // Push sub object to final array
    finalArray.push(subObj);
  } else if(arr[i].name === "start_section") {
    // If we get start_section
    // Set flag on
    inSubSection = true;
    // Set new sub object, set childs array in it
    subObj = {
      id: arr[i].id,
      name: "section",
      child: []
    };
  } else if(inSubSection) {
    // If we have active flag (true)
    // Push child to section array
    subObj.child.push({
      id: arr[i].id,
      name: arr[i].name
    });
  } else {
    // Everything else push straight to final array
    finalArray.push(arr[i]);
  }
}

// Log
console.log(finalArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function

```js
let array = [{id: 1, name: "header"},{id: 2, name: "start_section"},
 {id: 3, name: "input"}, {id: 5, name: "image"},
 {id: 6, name: "end_section"}, {id: 7, name: "header"},
 {id: 8, name: "start_section"}, {id: 9, name: "input"},
 {id: 10, name: "date"}, {id: 11, name: "end_section"},
]


let outPut = array.reduce( (acc, cur, i, arr) => {

  if (cur.name == "start_section") {
     
     //find the end element
     let endIndex = arr.slice(i).findIndex( e => e.name == "end_section") + i ;
     
     //splice the child elements from base array
     let child = arr.splice(i + 1, endIndex - 1 );

     //remove last element that has "end_section"
     child.splice(-1); 
     
     //append child
     cur.child = child;
     
     //sert the name as "section"
     cur.name = "section";
  }
  
  //add to accumulator
  acc.push(cur);  

return acc;
}, []);

console.log(outPut);
```